# Antonym of Abseil

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Abseil, or rappel in AmE, means “to descend using a rope”. Is there a word for “ascend using a rope”?

Comment: The obvious one is 'climb', is there a reason for not wanting to use that?

Comment: @KillingTime - By the same logic, why not just say “climb down” instead of “Abseil”?

Comment: You could use 'climb down' but with abseiling you're using gravity to drop down the rope, you can't use gravity to move up the rope so the activity is different.

Comment: Climbing up/down doesn’t necessarily imply using a rope.

Comment: As I already noted, there isn't a physical action that is the exact opposite of abseiling (i.e controlled falling) so there won't be an exact word for an activity that doesn't exist.

Comment: It's just called ascending. You use [ascenders](https://wiki.ezvid.com/best-ascenders?id=adw&gclid=CjwKCAjwrvv3BRAJEiwAhwOdM6v2gme4f3RIVBbAfmGqpJXkrKx1YgvdQDBbLgd-efd1k5IZpSqG1RoCXIgQAvD_BwE)

Comment: @KillingTime A controlled rise is what happens with indoor skydiving—where the person is pushed up by a blast of air. However, although that is controlled rising, I know of no single word for it.

Comment: @JasonBassford While that might be true, I doubt many people would class "indoor skydiving" as being the opposite of abseiling and the OP seems keen that the word or term implies the use of a rope to ascend.

Comment: Another term that might do is to *Scale* a precipice, though that could mean with just the assistance of a rope.

Comment: One could always use "levitate".  (Well, maybe not always.)

Comment: *"Abseil, or rappel in **English**, means “to descend using a rope”* **;)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abseil is of German origin (infinitive: *abseilen*). The German antonym would be *aufseilen*. Since aufseil has not made it into the English corpus, use **ascend** which is also the translation that fits best for *aufseilen*. The device used for this action is called an ascender - as has been pointed out in the comments already.

Comment: What about bungee jumping and springy ropes in general?  Are you *ascending* or merely *rebounding?*